# Is a 1st-level spell cast using a 4th-level slot a 1st-level spell, or a 4th-level spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots

As the title says: Is a 1st-level spell cast using a 4th-level slot a 1st-level spell, or a 4th-level spell?

Comment: Gonna show this to my group the next time they say that their Dispel Magic should've automatically ended a spell ordinarily of a lower level that was cast at a higher slot

Comment: @Tophandour just remember this was *not* the case in 3.5 - they have a reason to think what they think. It may be a habit, not ignorance or neglect.

Comment: Right. We still have a couple things of that sort floating around that we're trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The spell is a 4th level spell. (PHB, p.201)

> Casting a Spell at a Higher Level
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a
> higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher
> level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts magic
> missile using one of her 2nd-level slots, **that magic
> missile is 2nd level.** Effectively, the spell expands to fill
> the slot it is put into.

Comment: Is there any difference between a spell that "can" be casted as higher level (for extra damage, more targets, etc) with a spell that you cast using a higher slot? I mean, you can use your level 9 slot to cast a level 1 spell that it will not be more powerful for doing this. When it comes to Dispel o Counter for example, is this the same thing, right?

Comment: @Kelhendros Any spell can be cast using a higher level slot, and some spells gain specific benefits from it.

Comment: Actually only any spell that uses a slot can be cast using a higher level. And only some of those gain benefit from it. You can't up cast cantrips or spells from items..

Comment: However they would still get the additional protection from Dispel Magic and Counterspell for having used the higher level slot.

Comment: @illustro Though upcasting does not penetrate *[Globe of Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability)*, strangely enough.

Comment: @T.J.L. I don't see why it wouldn't. If I cast Fireball using a 7th level slot it is a 7th level spell for the purposes of globe of invulnerability and would affect creatures inside the globe.

Comment: Do you have a reference that states otherwise in the rules?

Comment: @illustro Because the text says it doesn't - "[...] even if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot. "

Comment: That would be a case of specific beats general then not a general rule. It's also a distinction I missed when I read over it quickly there.

Comment: @illustro Yes, yes it would. I tagged you because it was related to something you said, but mostly it was for the answerer, if he wanted to mention the a known (or maybe not known to some people) specific caveat in his answer.

Answer (score 37):

4th.

PHB Page 201 says

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting.