# How does the Divination wizard's Expert Divination feature work when you upcast a divination spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, spell-slots

The School of Divination for a wizard has the feature [Expert Divination](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#SchoolofDivination) at level 6 (PHB, p. 116):

> #### Expert Divination
>
> When you cast a divination spell of 2nd level or higher using a spell slot, you regain one expended spell slot. The slot you regain must be of a level lower than the spell you cast [...]

The wording of the feature is confusing to me.

If a 6th-level wizard used a 3rd-level spell slot to upcast Mind Spike (a 2nd-level spell), does the Expert Divination feature count it as a 2nd-level spell (the original level of the spell) or a 3rd-level spell (since it was cast with a 3rd-level spell slot)?

Comment: Related: [Is a 1st-level spell cast using a 4th-level slot a 1st-level spell, or a 4th-level spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89932/33707)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## The spell counts as the level at which you cast it

The rules on spellcasting (PHB, 201) cover that:

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level for that casting, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. (PHB. p 201)

If you upcast a 2nd divination spell to 3rd, you'll count it as a 3rd level spell and can regain a 1st or 2nd level spell slot.