# Does the ability check DC of Dispel Magic scale with the slot level or the original level of the spell cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, gm-techniques, combat, counterspelling

We just played our weekly game and one of our PCs cast *[dispel magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic)* and we got confused with the wording of the DC to dispel. Is the rise in DC based on the spell slot level used or the normal level of the spell?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. What game (and edition) are you asking about?

Comment: oh sorry haha 5th edition dungeons and dragons!

Comment: Related: [Is a 1st-level spell cast using a 4th-level slot a 1st-level spell, or a 4th-level spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89932/)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 17):

#### The DC to dispel a spell effect is based on the spell's slot level.

*Dispel magic* says:

> Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level.

The rules for spell slots say:

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts magic missile using one of her 2nd-level slots, that magic missile is 2nd level. Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into.

So a spell that is normally 1st level cast with a 4th level slot is a 4th level spell. Therefore the DC to dispel it would be 10 + 4 = 14. A spell's level is determined by the level of the slot used to cast it.

Comment: You should also mention that casting _Dispel Magic_ at a higher level can negate the need for a DC check. So if the original spell was cast at 4th level, if _Dispel Magic_ is also cast at 4th level, then no DC check is required. Basically if you meet or beat the level of the spell being cast, it works automatically..