# How do Dispel Magic and Counterspell interact with a spell cast through the Ascendant Dragon-Touched Focus as though it were 9th level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, counterspelling

[*Counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) and [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) call for an ability check if the target spell is 4th level or higher:

> If it is casting a spell of 4th level or higher, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a success, the creature's spell fails and has no effect.

> For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

The Ascendant [Dragon-Touched Focus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-touched-focus) has a feature which allows you to treat a spell as though it were cast at 9th level:

> when you cast a spell of 1st level or higher while holding this focus, you can treat the spell as if it were cast using a 9th-level spell slot.

Now, the usual function of this seems clear enough - if I cast *fireball* and use this feature, I roll 14d6 damage instead of the usual 8d6. What is not clear is how *other* creatures treat the spell.

When attempting to *counterspell* or use *dispel magic* on a spell "upcast" through this focus, do you treat the target spell as though it were cast at 9th level, or at the level it was actually cast?

Note, I use scare quotes around "upcast" because *the spell is cast using whatever spell slot you choose to use for it*. A 1st-level spell "upcast" with this feature still consumes a 1st-level spell slot.

Comment: When you cast a 1st level spell with the focus it is cast using a 1st level slot. This question is not a duplicate: [Is a 1st-level spell cast using a 4th-level slot a 1st-level spell, or a 4th-level spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89932)

Answer (score 8):

#### It acts exactly like an upcast spell

The [rule on casting a spell at a higher level](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpellataHigherLevel) states:

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts *magic missile* using one of her 2nd-level slots, that *magic missile* is 2nd level. Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into.

Using this, it's clear that *dispel magic* and *counterspell* would act against the spell slot used.

> when you cast a spell of 1st level or higher while holding this focus, you can treat the spell as if it were cast using a 9th-level spell slot.

So this mechanic makes the cast spell behave exactly as if it were cast using a 9th level slot.  **So *dispel magic* or *counterspell* need to succeed against a 9th-level spell.**